# Embedded tpl statements in helm

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I am working with helm.

I have a condtion where a variable in values.yaml ( variable name is db) will get conditional value (either oracle or postgres).

In the same values.yaml i have two sections containing respective properties for oracle & postgres.

How can I use the variable in db in nested manner? I want to avoid if else blocks.

I tried {{tpl .Values.{{tpl .Values.db .}}.port .}}. but it doesn't work.

Please find below code snippet

Values.yaml

```
db: postgres
postgres:
  port:5432
oracle:
  port:1521
```

templatefile.yaml

```
port: "{{tpl .Values.{{tpl .Values.db .}}.port .}}"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't nest the `{{ ... }}` blocks in the Helm templating language.

You can set a variable to the value of the inner "template" or just invoke it directly as an expression

```
{{- $dbname := tpl .Values.db . -}}
{{- printf "%s" (tpl .Values.db .) -}}
```

To actually use this as a field in the `.Values` structure, you need the [text/template](https://godoc.org/text/template) `index` function.

```
{{- $settings := index .Values (tpl .Values.db .) -}}
port: "{{ $settings.port }}"
```